# How do I create ranking (descending) table in matlab based on inputs from two separate data tables?

Tags: matlab, ranking, bucket-sort

I have four data sets (please bear with me here):

- 1st Table: List of 10 tickers (stock symbols) in one column in txt format in matlab.
- 2nd table: dates in numerical format in one column (10 days in double format).
- 3rd table: I have 10*10 data set of random numbers (assume 0-1 for simplicity). (Earnings Per Share growth EPS for example)--so I want high EPS growth in my ranking for portfolio construction.
- 4th table: I have another 10*10 data set of random numbers (assume 0-1 for simplicity). (Price to earnings ratios for example daily).-so I want low P/E ratio in my ranking for portfolio construction.

NOW: I want to rank portfolio of stocks each day made up of 3 stocks (largest values) from table one for a particular day and bottom three stocks from table 2 (smallest values). The output must be list of tickers for each day (3 in this case) based on combined ranking of the two factors (table 3 & 4 as described).

Any ideas? In short I need to end up with a top bucket with three tickers...

Comment: What is the purpose of table 3 and 4? what are the contents of tables 3 and 4? are they per-day data for each ticker in table 1?

Comment: Collaborative editing is part of SO http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing "If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you." Consider editing your post yourself, abstracting your problem in terms of data and input/output and maybe providing an example case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear from the post what you are trying to achieve. Here is a take based on guessing, with various options.

Your first two "tables" store symbols for stocks and days (irrelevant for ranking). Your third and fourth are scores arranged in a `stock x day` manner. Let's assume stocks vertical, days horizontal and stocks symbolized with a value in `[1:10]`.

```
N = 10; % num of stocks
M = 10; % num of days   
T3 = rand(N,M); % table 3 stocks x days
T4 = rand(N,M); % table 4 stocks x days
```

Sort the score tables in ascending and descending order (to get upper and lower scores per day, i.e. per column):

```
[Sl,L] = sort(T3, 'descend'); 
[Ss,S] = sort(T4, 'ascend');
```

Keep three largest and smallest:

```
largest = L(1:3,:);  % bucket of 3 largest per day
smallest = S(1:3,:); % bucket of 3 smallest per day
```

IF you need the ones in both (0 is nan):

```
% Inter-section of both buckets
indexI = zeros(3,M);
for i=1:M
    z = largest(ismember(largest(:,i),smallest(:,i)));
    if ~isempty(z)
        indexI(1:length(z),i) = z;
    end
end
```

IF you need the ones in either one (0 is nan):

```
% Union of both buckets
indexU = zeros(6,M);
for i=1:M
    z = unique([largest(:,i),smallest(:,i)]);
    indexU(1:length(z),i) = z;
end
```

IF you need a ranking of scores/stocks from the set of largest_of_3 and smallest_of_4:

```
scoreAll = [Sl(1:3,:); Ss(1:3,:)];
indexAll = [largest;smallest];

[~,indexSort] = sort(scoreAll,'descend');
for i=1:M
    indexBest(:,i) = indexAll(indexSort(1:3,i),i);
end
```

**UPDATE**

To get a weighted ranking of the final scores, define the weight vector (1 x scores) and use one of the two options below, before sorting `scoreAllW` instead of `scoreAll`:

```
w = [0.3 ;0.3; 0.3; 0.7; 0.7; 0.7];
scoreAllW = scoreAll.*repmat(w,1,10);    % Option 1
scoreAllW = bsxfun(@times, scoreAll, w); % Option 2
```

Comment: Dear Gevang, many thanks for your help full contribution, it makes perfect sense. Quick question, how would I modify the weighting for  each factor for the final output? Meaning in the last stage, suppose I want .3 weighting for the T3 and .7 for T4 before I get the final output in indexBest?

Comment: @Noob_1 You can either pre-weight T3 and T4 by the selected weights (w1 and w2), or wight the `scoreAll` matrix before the final `sort.` See the update in my answer.